# I can see/send invites to non-app user friends on canvas app but not on android/ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am using the facebook sdk for unity and testing out app requests using the following call:

```
FB.AppRequest(
            FriendSelectorMessage,
            null,
            FriendSelectorFiltersArr,
            excludeIds,
            maxRecipients,
            FriendSelectorData,
            FriendSelectorTitle,
            Callback
            );
```

The above call returns a native invite dialog list of all my friends when testing in the canvas version of the app, however when I compile for android/Ios, I only get a list of friends who have played the app??

Is there anyway I can see all friends on ios/android as well?